disable pagination crud generator nest js data/ui
I tried everything I could to turn off pagination and exclude limit page and override the getManyBase method via override, but I still can’t turn it off and at the end of the request I get
http://localhost:10000/api/clubadmin/clubs?limit=1&page=1
"count": 1,
"total": 29,
"page": 1,
"pageCount": 29
My controller
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  NotFoundException,
  Param,
  Query,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClubsService } from './clubs.service';
import { getLocalTimeAsUTC, parseDate, toSchedule } from 'src/global/helper';
import { Sport } from 'src/matches/matches.interface';
import { Crud, CrudAuth, CrudController } from '@dataui/crud';
import { Club } from './entities/club.entity';
import { User } from 'src/users/entities/user.entity';
import { CustomRegexArrayPipe } from 'src/global';
import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/mapped-types';
import { Media } from 'src/media/media.decorator';
import { MediaType } from 'src/media/media.interface';
import { CurrentUser } from 'src/auth/auth.decorators';
import { PaymentsService } from 'src/payment/payments.service';
import { Role } from 'src/users/roles.enum';
import { MatchBookingsService } from 'src/match-bookings/match-bookings.service';
import { IsNull, Not } from 'typeorm';

@Controller('/api/clubs')
export class ClubsController {
  constructor(
    private readonly service: ClubsService,
    private readonly matchBookingsService: MatchBookingsService,
  ) {}

  @Get()
  async getMany(
    @Query(
      'gamedates',
      new CustomRegexArrayPipe({
        property: 'gamedates',
        regex: /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/,
        optional: true,
      }),
    )
    gameDates?: string[],
    @Query(
      'clubs',
      new CustomRegexArrayPipe({
        property: 'clubs',
        regex: /^[1-9]\d*$/,
        optional: true,
      }),
    )
    clubIds?: string[],
    @Query('timefrom') timeFrom?: string,
    @Query('timeto') timeTo?: string,
    @Query('lat') lat?: string,
    @Query('long') long?: string,
    @Query('sport') sport?: Sport,
  ) {
    gameDates = gameDates?.filter((date) => Date.parse(date) >= Date.now());
    if (!gameDates?.length) {
      gameDates = [new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-ca')];
    }
    gameDates.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b));
    const gameDatesRanges = gameDates
      .map((date) => {
        const from = new Date(date).toISOString();
        const to = new Date(Date.parse(date) + 86400 * 1000).toISOString();
        return `(${from}, ${to})`;
      })
      .join(',');

    const parsedTimeFrom = timeFrom && parseDate(undefined, timeFrom);
    let parsedTimeTo = timeTo && parseDate(undefined, timeTo);
    if (timeTo && parsedTimeTo < parsedTimeFrom) parsedTimeTo += 86400000;

    const query = this.service.repo
      .createQueryBuilder('clubs')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('clubs.images', 'images')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('clubs.courts', 'courts')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('courts.schedule', 'schedule')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        'courts.bookings',
        'bookings',
        'bookings.interval && :gameDate::tsmultirange',
        { gameDate: `{${gameDatesRanges}}` },
      );

    if (Array.isArray(clubIds)) {
      query.andWhere('clubs.id IN (:...clubIds)', {
        clubIds: clubIds,
      });
    }

    if (sport) {
      query.andWhere('courts.sport = :sport', { sport: sport });
    }

    if (lat && long) {
      query.orderBy(
        'ST_Distance(clubs.location, ST_MakePoint(:long, :lat))',
        'ASC',
      );
      query.setParameters({ long, lat });
    }

    const clubs = await query.getMany();

    clubs.forEach((club) => {
      const localClubTime = getLocalTimeAsUTC(new Date(), club.timezone);
      gameDates.forEach((gameDate) => {
        const weekDay = new Date(gameDate).getUTCDay();
        const availableSlots = {};
        club.courts?.forEach((court) => {
          const bookingMap = {};
          court.bookings?.forEach((booking) => {
            booking.series?.forEach((slot) => {
              bookingMap[slot.getTime()] = true;
            });
          });

          const scheduleMap = {};
          court.schedule?.forEach((scheduleRow) => {
            scheduleRow.series?.forEach((time) => {
              const parsedDatetime = parseDate(scheduleRow.date, time, 'Z');
              scheduleMap[parsedDatetime] = scheduleRow.price || 1;
            });
          });

          court.schedule?.forEach((scheduleRow) => {
            if (scheduleRow.weekDay !== weekDay) return;
            scheduleRow.series?.forEach((time) => {
              const parsedTime = parseDate(undefined, time);
              const parsedDatetime = parseDate(gameDate, time, 'Z');
              if (timeTo && parsedTime > parsedTimeTo) return;
              if (timeFrom && parsedTime < parsedTimeFrom) return;
              if (parsedDatetime < localClubTime.getTime()) return;

              const t1 = parsedDatetime;
              const t2 = parsedDatetime + 30 * 60 * 1000;
              const t3 = parsedDatetime + 60 * 60 * 1000;
              const t4 = parsedDatetime + 90 * 60 * 1000;
              const c1 = scheduleMap[toSchedule(t1)];
              const c2 = scheduleMap[toSchedule(t2)];
              const c3 = scheduleMap[toSchedule(t3)];
              const c4 = scheduleMap[toSchedule(t4)];
              const b1 = bookingMap[t1];
              const b2 = bookingMap[t2];
              const b3 = bookingMap[t3];
              const b4 = bookingMap[t4];

              const getMaxPlayTime = () => {
                if (c1 && c2 && c3 && c4 && !b1 && !b2 && !b3 && !b4)
                  return 120;
                if (c1 && c2 && c3 && !b1 && !b2 && !b3) return 90;
                if (c1 && c2 && !b1 && !b2) return 60;
              };

              const playTime = getMaxPlayTime();
              const slicedTime = time.slice(0, 5);
              const currentPlayTime =
                availableSlots?.[slicedTime]?.playTime || 0;
              if (playTime) {
                const minPrice = c1 + c2;
                if (!club.minPrice || minPrice < club.minPrice) {
                  club.minPrice = minPrice;
                }
              }
              if (playTime > currentPlayTime) {
                availableSlots[slicedTime] = { time: slicedTime, playTime };
              }
            });
          });
        });
        club.availableTimes = club.availableTimes || {};
        club.availableTimes[gameDate] = Object.values(availableSlots);
        club.availableTimes[gameDate].sort(
          (a, b) => parseDate(undefined, a.time) - parseDate(undefined, b.time),
        );
      });
      club.courts = undefined;
    });
    return clubs;
  }

  @Get('/all')
  async getAllClubs(
    @Query('lat') lat: string,
    @Query('long') long: string,
    @Query('sport') sport: Sport,
  ) {
    let query = this.service.repo
      .createQueryBuilder('clubs')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('clubs.images', 'images')
      .leftJoin('clubs.courts', 'courts');

    if (lat && long) {
      query.addSelect(
        'ST_Distance(clubs.location, ST_MakePoint(:long, :lat)) / 1000',
        'clubs_range',
      );
      query = query.setParameters({ long, lat });
      query = query.orderBy('clubs_range', 'ASC');
    }

    if (sport) {
      query = query.andWhere('courts.sport = :sport', { sport: sport });
    }
    return await query.getMany();
  }

  @Get('/:id')
  async getOneWithDate(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Query('gamedate') gameDate: string,
  ) {
    return await this.service.getClubInfo(id, gameDate);
  }

  @Get('simple/:id')
  async getOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const club = await this.service.repo
      .createQueryBuilder('clubs')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('clubs.images', 'images')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('clubs.tags', 'tags')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('clubs.courts', 'courts')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('courts.schedule', 'schedule')
      .where({ id })
      .getOne();
    if (!club) return [];
    if (club.courts && Array.isArray(club.courts)) {
      const countCourts = club.courts.length;
      const sports = [];
      club.courts.forEach((court) => {
        if (!sports.includes(court.sport)) {
          sports.push(court.sport);
        }
      });
      Object.assign(club, { countCourts, sports });
      return club;
    }
  }

  @Get(':id/feedbacks')
  async getManyFeedbacks(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const feedbacks = await this.matchBookingsService.repo.find({
      where: {
        rating: Not(IsNull()),
        match: { booking: { court: { club: { id: Number(id) } } } },
      },
      relations: { player: { user: { avatar: true } } },
    });
    const sum = feedbacks.reduce(
      (acc, feedback) => acc + (feedback.rating || 0),
      0,
    );
    const rating = Number((sum / feedbacks.length).toFixed(1)) || null;
    return { feedbacks, rating };
  }
}

@Crud({
  model: { type: Club },
  dto: {
    create: Club,
    update: PartialType(Club),
  },
  routes: {
    createOneBase: {
      decorators: [Media(Club, { images: { type: MediaType.IMAGE } })],
    },
    updateOneBase: {
      decorators: [Media(Club, { images: { type: MediaType.IMAGE } })],
    },
  },
  query: {
    join: {
      user: {
        eager: true,
      },
      tags: {
        eager: true,
      },
      images: {
        eager: true,
      },
    },
    alwaysPaginate: false,
  },
})
@CrudAuth({
  property: 'user',
  filter: (user: User) => {
    if (user.roles.includes(Role.ADMIN)) return {};
    return { 'user.id': user.id };
  },
  persist: (user: User) => ({
    user: { id: user.id },
  }),
})
@Controller('/api/clubadmin/clubs')
export class ClubsAdminController implements CrudController<Club> {
  constructor(
    public service: ClubsService,
    readonly paymentsService: PaymentsService,
  ) {}

  @Get('/:id/balance')
  async getBalance(@CurrentUser() user: User, @Param('id') id: string) {
    const getClub = async () => {
      if (user.roles.includes(Role.ADMIN)) {
        return await this.service.repo.findOneBy({ id: Number(id) });
      } else {
        return user.clubs.find((club) => club.id === Number(id));
      }
    };
    const club = await getClub();
    if (!club) throw new NotFoundException('Клуб не найден');

    const balance = await this.paymentsService.getClubBalance(club);
    return { balance };
  }
}


My club entity
import { Court } from 'src/courts/entities/court.entity';
import { Media } from 'src/media/entities/Media';
import { ClubTag } from 'src/tags/entities/clubTag.entity';
import { User } from 'src/users/entities/user.entity';
import {
  AfterLoad,
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  Index,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  Point,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  VirtualColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { tz } from 'moment-timezone';
import {
  IsArray,
  IsBoolean,
  IsIn,
  IsObject,
  IsOptional,
  IsString,
  IsTimeZone,
} from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { Player } from 'src/players/entities/player.entity';

class Point2 {
  type = 'Point';
  coordinates: number[];
}

@Entity('clubs')
export class Club {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  @IsString()
  title: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Media, (media) => media.clubImages)
  images: Media;

  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  user: User;

  @OneToMany(() => Court, (court) => court.club)
  courts: Court[];

  @ManyToMany(() => ClubTag, (tag) => tag.clubs)
  @JoinTable()
  @IsArray()
  @Type(() => ClubTag)
  tags: ClubTag[];

  @Index({ spatial: true })
  @Column({
    type: 'geography',
    spatialFeatureType: 'Point',
    srid: 4326,
    nullable: true,
  })
  @IsObject()
  @Type(() => Point2)
  location: Point;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', default: 'UTC' })
  @IsTimeZone()
  timezone: string;

  @VirtualColumn({ query: () => 'SELECT NULL' })
  timezoneOffset: string;
  @AfterLoad()
  setTimezoneOffset() {
    this.timezoneOffset = tz(this.timezone).format('Z');
  }

  @Column()
  @IsString()
  city: string;

  @Column()
  @IsString()
  country: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  district: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  street: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  postalCode: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  description: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  website: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  phoneNumber: string;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  @IsIn([0, 3, 6, 12, 24])
  cancellationPolicy: number;

  @Column({ default: true })
  @IsBoolean()
  @IsOptional()
  allowClasses: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  bankAccount?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  bankBic?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  bankCorr?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  bankInn?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  bankKpp?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  availableSlots?: Record<
    string,
    {
      available: Omit<Court, 'schedule' | 'bookings'>[];
      booked: (Omit<Court, 'schedule' | 'bookings'> & {
        players: Player[];
      })[];
    }
  >;

  availableTimes?: object;

  minPrice: number;

  @Column({ select: false, nullable: true })
  range: number;
}


I tried this
@Crud({
  model: { type: Club },
  dto: {
    create: Club,
    update: PartialType(Club),
  },
  routes: {
    createOneBase: {
      decorators: [Media(Club, { images: { type: MediaType.IMAGE } })],
    },
    updateOneBase: {
      decorators: [Media(Club, { images: { type: MediaType.IMAGE } })],
    },
  },
  query: {
    join: {
      user: {
        eager: true,
      },
      tags: {
        eager: true,
      },
      images: {
        eager: true,
      },
    },
    alwaysPaginate: false, // off paginate
  },
})

I tried this
@Override('getManyBase')
  async getMany(@ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest): Promise<GetManyDefaultResponse<Club> | Club[]> {
    req.parsed.limit = undefined;
    req.parsed.page = undefined;

    return this.service.getManyOverride(req);
  }

I tried this
@Override()
  @Get()
  async getMany(@ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest): Promise<Club[]> {
    req.parsed.limit = undefined;
    req.parsed.page = undefined;
    return this.service.getMany(req);
  }

